# How to use the JavaScript code from a js file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the JavaScript code from a `.js` file.
My code works fine when I keep this code in the `.html` file within the script tags.

What changes should I make when I move the script to a `.js` file.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='cc'><img src="images/cat1.png"><br /></div>
    <div>The number of times you clicked the cat is:</div><br />
    <div id='times'>0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var pic = document.getElementById('cc');
pic.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var count = document.getElementById('times').innerHTML;
    count = parseInt(count) + 1;
    document.getElementById('times').innerHTML = count;
}, false);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wrap that code inside `window.onload` to make it run after all the DOM elements are loaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
 var pic = document.getElementById('cc');
 pic.addEventListener('click', function() {
     var count = document.getElementById('times').innerHTML;
     count = parseInt(count) + 1;
     document.getElementById('times').innerHTML = count;
 }, false);
}
```

Else just move the script tag to the bottom of the page just above `</body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='cc'><img src="images/cat1.png"><br /></div>
    <div>The number of times you clicked the cat is:</div><br />
    <div id='times'>0</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your JavaScript code attempted to get an element which has not been rendered by the browser.

**Solution # 1**

You can try loading the JavaScript file after all elements have been rendered like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='cc'><img src="images/cat1.png"><br /></div>
    <div>The number of times you clicked the cat is:</div><br />
    <div id='times'>0</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution # 2**

You can also try using jQuery and do the following:

```
$(function(){
    // and also convert this to its jQuery counterpart
    var pic = document.getElementById('cc');
    pic.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var count = document.getElementById('times').innerHTML;
        count = parseInt(count) + 1;
        document.getElementById('times').innerHTML = count;
    }, false);
})
```

If these didn't work, try using the Chrome developer tools and check if js/app.js is pointing to the JavaScript file